# react native:Unable to set custom height to modal

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I am new to react-native and I am trying to give custom height to modal and to be centered in the screen using the following code.

```
  <Modal visible={this.state.isModalVisible} animationType = "slide" transparent = {false} 
     onRequestClose={this.closeModal} style={{ height:300 }}>
            <View style={{
               flex: 1,
               flexDirection: 'column',
               justifyContent: 'center',
               alignItems: 'center',
               backgroundColor:'blue'
              }}>
            <View>
             <Text style={{ fontWeight:'bold', fontSize: 20, color: '#f79334', marginTop: 15 
        }} > Services </Text>
            </View>
            </View>
  </Modal>
```

Comment: you can give custom height as ```height: 'height'``` to your parent View component.

Comment: @sdushan i have tried this but not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your height to the content `View` instead

```
   <Modal style={{  margin: 0, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 400,
          width: '100%',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }}
      >
        <View>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: '#f79334',
              marginTop: 15,
            }}
          >
            Services
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: @Mahi what was the outcome ? .. .cause it's working as expected on my end

Comment: on my end it is taking 100% height and width, I want to give custom height and should display it in the center.

Comment: thanks @hend-el-sahli it's working as expected, you nailed it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make the modal transparent (by using the Modal's transparent prop) and set the height of the child, View element. The code should roughly look like:

```
import { Modal, Text, View } from "react-native";

import FormButton from "../FormButton";
import { StandardModalPropsType } from "./types";

export default function StandardModal({ openModal, isModalOpen, title, message }: StandardModalPropsType) {
    return (
        <Modal animationType="slide" visible={isModalOpen} transparent>
            {/*The child element that determines the height of the modal.*/}
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 0.5,
                    justifyContent: "flex-start",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(7, 53, 105,0.979)",
                    height: 500,
                    marginTop: 200,
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    marginRight: 10,
                    borderRadius: 36,
                    elevation: 8,
                    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
                    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
                    shadowRadius: 6
                }}
            >
                <View>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            textAlign: "center",
                            fontFamily: "nunitoBold",
                            color: "red",
                            fontSize: 25,
                            margin: 26,
                            textDecorationLine: "underline"
                        }}
                    >
                        {title}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            textAlign: "center",
                            fontFamily: "nunito",
                            color: "white",
                            fontSize: 20,
                            marginTop: 40
                        }}
                    >
                        {message}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 20,
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignItems: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    {/*Custom button component*/}
                    <FormButton
                        backgroundColor="rgb(255, 255, 255)"
                        color="rgb(7, 53, 105)"
                        onPress={() => {
                            openModal(!isModalOpen);
                        }}
                    >
                        OK
                    </FormButton>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

The output would look like:
[image]

Hope this was useful.